# Column does not exists when accessing inner type field in ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, database-design, order-by, composite-types

In *PostgreSQL 9.4* I have two types:

```
CREATE TYPE a_schema.type_child {  
  an_order smallint
}

CREATE TYPE a_schema.type_parent {
  pluto uuid,
  child type_child
}
```

Then in a view I have this script:

```
SELECT 
    something_a,
    something_b,

    ARRAY(SELECT
            ROW (a_uuid,
              a_schema.get_a_type_child(a_type_child_id)
            )::a_schema.type_parent AS tp
          FROM a_schema.a_table
          ORDER BY ((tp).type_child).an_order ASC)
FROM ....
```

where the stored procedure just does a select as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION a_schema.get_a_type_child(IN type_id smallint, OUT a_type a_schema.type_child)
  RETURNS a_schema.type_child AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN

  SELECT
      ROW (a_order)::a_schema.type_child
  FROM a_schema_another_table
  WHERE at_id = type_id
  LIMIT 1
  INTO a_type;

END;

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER COST 1;
```

The error I get is:

> ERROR: column "tp" does not exist

related to the `ORDER BY` clause.

I know that I could just do

```
ORDER BY tp
```

But then I have to define an ordering for the type, which introduces a lot of code.

Is there any way to access the inner type field `an_order` for ordering purpose?

Comment: Show us the `CREATE TABLE a_table;` code.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ right, I make it easier to read but it is wrong. The subtype comes from a sproc, I'll update the question.

Comment: You can't reference an alias like that in the order by clause. You need to wrap that into a derived table. I also think you are over complicating things by using types like that. Your queries would be a **lot** easier if you would just store the information in a normalized way as regular columns - but that might just be me,

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name.  It sounds like a target for some more design thinking.  Furthermore, you could define that function as a SQL language one, removing the PL/pgSQL clutter.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah, I'm doing this because of some needs on the library that is used to convert everything into a Java code. Could you post an answer with some examples of your ideas?

Comment: @dezso sorry for the novice question, is there any benefit in using the SQL language in the sproc?

Comment: @mat_boy if nothing else, it helps readability, reduces the number of context switches when executing queries, furthermore in some cases it might render the function inlineable: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions

Comment: @dezso: True, but `SECURITY DEFINER` functions are exempt from inlining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Explanation for the error

You get the error message:

> ERROR: column "tp" does not exist

because you cannot use output columns in another *expression* in the `ORDER BY` clause. You can only reference output column names *as a whole*. Expressions must be built on *input* columns. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY)

> Each expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column
>   (`SELECT` list item), or it can be an arbitrary **expression formed from
>   input-column values**.

Bold emphasis mine.

#### Solution

You would need the row type as *input* to your query to involve it in expressions in `ORDER BY`. You can do that with a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT 
    something_a,
    something_b,
    ARRAY (
      SELECT (a_uuid, my_child)::a_schema.type_parent AS tp
      FROM   a_schema.a_table
      LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (SELECT get_a_type_child(a_type_child_id) AS my_child) t ON true
      ORDER  BY (t.my_child).an_order
      )
FROM ....
```

Why `LEFT JOIN LATERAL () ON true`?

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

#### Asides

The solution is merely a ***proof of concept***. You need intimate knowledge of row and composite type handling to cope with this setup, and it will still be awkward and slow. Your setup is more complicated than necessary to begin with. I would have to type so much to explain everything, it's just not worth it.

I [agree with @a_horse](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149502/column-does-not-exists-when-accessing-inner-type-fields-in-postgresql#comment284452_149502): a properly normalized schema will save you a lot of headache.

The function can be simpler, but there is nothing wrong with PL/pgSQL per se. `SECURITY DEFINER` functions are exempt from function inlining anyway. There are other pros and cons for SQL vs. PL/pgSQL functions:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755468/difference-between-language-sql-and-language-plpgsql-in-postgresql-functions/24771561#24771561)

Note: *functions*. Your term *stored procedure* is a bit off, since Postgres does not have true stored procedures. Just functions - doing almost but not quite the same.